# ruby on rails fetch activerecords with where clause

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, model, has-many

I have a simple question - basically I want to fetch all ActiveRecords of some model X which adhere to some conditions. I am trying to use the X.where method here but I am not sure how it will work. Basically, my model X has_many Y.

I have a list of ids for model Y objects. I want to find all of model X which has at least one of those ids in its has_many Y.

Is there a simple way I can do this using X.where? Or do i need more complicated sql?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I would do:

```
Modelx.joins(:modelys).where(:modelys => { :id => list_of_ids }).all
```

Another solution that I prefer is to use scopes:

```
def Modelx < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :modelys
  has_many :modelzs

  scope :has_modely_ids, lambda { |ids| joins(:modelys).where(:modelys => { :id => [*ids] }) }
  scope :has_modelz_ids, lambda { |ids| joins(:modelzs).where(:modelzs => { :id => [*ids] }) }

end
```

then you can do stuff like:

```
Modelx.has_modely_ids(y_ids).all
Modelx.has_modelz_ids(z_ids).all

modelx_with_ys = Modelx.has_modely_ids(y_ids)
modelx_with_zs = Modelz.has_modely_ids(y_ids)
```

or chaining: (just rememeber to call all when you actually want to run the query)

```
modelx_with_y_and_zs = Modelx.has_modely_ids(y_ids).has_modelz_ids(z_ids)
modelx_with_y_and_zs = modelx_with_ys.has_modelz_ids(z_ids)
```

Comment: Would this scale efficiently with multiple conditions? Say X has_many Z. And I also have a list of ids for Z. I want to find X s.t. it has a Y with id in the Y id list AND Z with id in the Z id list. Would Modelx.joins(:modelys).joins(:modelzs).where(:modelys => { :id => list_of_y_ids }, :modelzs => { :id => list_of_z_ids }) work and if so, would it be the most efficient way?

Comment: I added some examples of using scopes.  I've found it scales well, but depending on your situation there is always room to improve.

Comment: How about when querying on intersections? For example, if I wanted Modelx that has Y id 'a' and 'b'. The above will give me Modelx's that have either 'a' or 'b'. I would need to perform Modelx.has_modely_ids(a).has_modely_ids(b) to get the intersection. This doesn't seem to scale with more ids. Is there a better way to handle this use case? Thanks!

Comment: You can build scopes for anything that you'd like–even writing sql queries directly for advanced situation. If you have a specific problem that you want to solve, I'd say ask another question in StackOverflow. Rails is a good platform; not perfect.